# Retrieving docker images from an old hard drive

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

Yesterday, I accidently deleted the `/bin` folder in the root folder of my ubuntu installation.

I thus had to reinstall ubuntu. I backed up the entire disk where I had installed docker and was running docker containers. Essentially, I just backed up the computer and re-installed ubuntu. Now that I have a fresh install of ubuntu, I installed docker again, and I am trying to retrieve all the images I had, which should be backed up since the whole drive was backed up. I can access the drive and all the files on it, I am just not sure where I can find the docker images. Unfortunately, I cannot just use the dockerfiles as I have been using `docker commit` to create snapshot images in order to back up containers up until now (I know this isnt best practice) and if I were to resort to building from the original dockerfile I would lose roughly 1-1.5 years of work (running agile, so you can imagine how many sprints worth of work would be lost given each sprint is roughly one week).

**tldr: Had a computer, had to re install the os, backed up everything, now trying recover the docker images.**

Thank you for your time! I appreciate any help.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You might try stopping Docker and then replacing all of `/var/lib/docker` from the backup.

Comment: Have you done back up of your images using `docker save` that will save in say .tgz format?

Comment: @ David Maze, This worked, thank you very much! I had an inkling I could do something like this, but after reading some other posts, I was not sure which root path, usr/bin/docker, or var/lib/docker to copy over so I disregarded that route. Thank you for your suggestion, this really helped. I will now be working to use these images to create an updated dockerfile and set up a versioning system to prevent this from happening again. Thanks again!